Symfony custom class attribute
I want to use this in my controllers:
#[VerifyPermissions('writeDocs')]
public function testAction()
{
    return new JsonResponse(["status" => "OK"]);
}

This is my VerifyPermissions class:
#[\Attribute]
class VerifyPermissions
{
    public function __construct(
        private EntityManagerInterface $em,
        private TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage,
        private string $permissionsToCheck
    ) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        ...
    }
}

But I got this error:
Argument #1 ($em) must be of type Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, string given

I though adding some autowire config in the services.yaml like:
App\Security\VerifyPermissions:
    arguments:
        $em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        $tokenStorage: "@security.token_storage"

But this does not work.

It looks like you are attempting to verify a user has permission to accomplish a task. This is exactly the purpose of Voters. I recommend you utilize a custom Voter to accomplish this. https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

I will check that out, thanks, still I'd like to know if my code can be fix and what's wrong...
